# Closing one's own question as a dupe

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I was curious why does it permit users to close their own question. What is the rational behind this? Is there any reason a user should be allowed to do this?

Comment: If OP votes to close as duplicate, that is the final vote, and it is closed immediately.

Comment: Oh, my bad @DrGreenEggsandIronMan

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan does that apply to other close reasons?

Comment: On a Q&A site, duplicate questions act as signposts to the original question, so that people who ask in a different wording will find the duplicate, and hence find the original. So a user could post and close a question to create such a signpost. That purpose doesn't really work on PPCG though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the traditional Q&A sites on the network, the question asker has a problem in mind that they are trying to solve when they ask their question. When another user casts a close-as-duplicate vote, the OP is given a dialog to close the question as a duplicate that says, "Yes, [the dupe target question] answered my question". This makes sense on Q&A-oriented sites.

On the non-Q&A sites on the network (PPCG, Code Review, and Puzzling), the situation is a bit different. Posters don't have questions that they need answered - they have challenges to pose to the community (PPCG and Puzzling), or have working code that they want feedback on (Code Review), so the wording on the dialog is less than ideal. In a perfect world, on these sites, the OP's vote would not weigh any more heavily than the other users' votes. Unfortunately, the Stack Exchange team is unlikely to make those customizations for just three sites, so we have to live with the current system.

Comment: *"In a perfect world, on these sites, the OP's vote would not weigh any more heavily than the other users' votes."* I disagree completely. If the OP sees another challenge and realizes that what they had in mind already exists, they should have the ability to close their own question without having to wait through a close vote queue. It's one of the things that, despite having wording that doesn't quite mesh with our site, makes sense from a functionality standpoint on *all* sites on the network, including us, Puzzling, and CR.